# How to retrieve Workspace ID using computername/hostname in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I understand the describe-workspaces command has a way to retrieve the details of a workspace with workspace-id. But wanted to know if there is a way to retrieve the same workspace-id with the help of Computername/hostname as input to any command.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workspaces/describe-workspaces.html